Is every sentence (without parameters) decidable in the forcing language?
Let $B$ be a complete Boolean algebra (optionally generated by a separative partial order $P$ with maximum), and $\varphi$ be a sentence without parameters in the language of set theory $\{\in\}$.
Is it true that either $1 \Vdash \varphi$ or $1 \Vdash \neg\varphi$ (where $1$ is the maximum of $B$)?
Translated to Boolean-valued models, my question becomes whether $\|\varphi\|$ is always either $0$ or $1$.

Context
This is just a curiosity that I had when I was reading through forcing, and intuitively I thought that without any parameters the truth should not depend on the forcing conditions $p \in B$.
If we allow parameters, and $p$ and $q$ are incompatible conditions, then surely we can construct a name $\dot{x}$ such that $p \Vdash \varnothing \in \dot{x}$ and $q \Vdash \varnothing \notin \dot{x}$. However, intuitively, if there are no parameters, then a $\forall$ quantifier would have to consider both $\dot{x}$ and the other set that satisfies the opposite condition, so something like $\forall x (\varnothing \in x)$ would simply be false no matter what $p$ is.
In other words, any quantifier should "average out" the values of the sub-formulas.

Potential Clues
I think the fact that forcing is used for consistency proofs hints at the answer being false. If $\varphi$ is a sentence independent of ZFC, then $\|\varphi\|$ should in theory be strictly between $0$ and $1$... (the implication goes the wrong way though, i.e. if $\|\varphi\| \ne 0,1$ then $\varphi$ is independent, not the other way round.)

No, not in general. Keyword: weakly homogeneous forcing.

Thanks for the keyword, I see that there is a classification of it in MO. I now wonder if we can make any explicit counter-example.

Sure, take two completely unrelated forcing posets and stick them side by side.

Yes, and by the classification I referred to, this poset will not be $V$-decisive; but what is an (explicit) example of $\varphi$ that $V$ fails to decide?

Like we can take the lottery sum (i.e. just stick together side by side, placing a new top element above everything) of some standard forcing poset that forces $CH$ and some standard poset that forces $\lnot CH$ and then in the lottery sum neither $CH$ nor $\lnot CH$ is forced (by the new top element $1$).

I see. To be more explicit I suppose we take ground model $M$ satisfying $V=L$, and then the trivial poset forces $CH$ and the standard poset involving $\omega_2 \times \omega$ forces $\neg CH$?

I was thinking of using a poset (e.g. countable partial functions $\omega_1\to \mathfrak c$) that forces CH without the help of extra axioms in the ground model, but that works.
